# Undecorated JFrame can't be dragged to the top of the Ubuntu screen properly

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

I have an undecorated `JFrame` with `JPanel` which is for dragging the window on the screen. It works, but when I want to drag it completely to the top of the screen it can't go there. There is space between window and top bar. I'm enclosing the screenshot and code. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Is there a way how to fix that?

[image: Look at that space]

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private int mouse_x_offset;
    private int mouse_y_offset;

    public Window() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(250, 250);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);

        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new PanelListener());
        panel.addMouseListener(new PanelListener());

        add(panel);
    }

    class PanelListener implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getXOnScreen();
            int y = e.getYOnScreen();

            setLocation(x - mouse_x_offset, y - mouse_y_offset);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouse_x_offset = e.getX();
            mouse_y_offset = e.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window window = new Window();
    }

}
```

Comment: What happen when set location to 0, 0 in your code ?

Comment: Edit: Yes. It goes right to the top left-hand corner without space.

Comment: Try to put negative values, maybe the frame decoration exists but is just invisible.

Comment: There is no problem with setLocation, it works. Problem is when I drag with the window it disappear from the top left-hand corner to the top left-hand corner with these spaces from left and top.

Comment: On Windows your code doesn't work at all because you add the panel to the frame after the frame is visible so the size of the panel is (0, 0) and the panel never receives any events. The setVisible(...) statement should only be executed after all components have been added to the frame. When I fixed that the code worked fine for me. Don't know why Ubuntu would be different.

Comment: You don't need to create two listeners. That is the mouse offset variables should be part of your listener class, not the main class. Then your PanelListener class becomes reusable as all the code is self contained. Also, don't call your class Window since there is an AWT component with that name. Your name should be more descriptive.